# Angular 6 call backend api before routing is started

Tags: angular, routes, angular-router

I have a angular 6 application.New Users need to go throw a quick setup before they can use the application.

I am using a backend api to check the users status and see if the user has finished the initial setup.

I am calling this api in `AppComponent::ngOnInit` and also `LoginConponent::ngOnInit` , this works fine if user is visiting `/` or its unauthorized, because after external login user will be redirected to `/login`.

But if the user types in the url manually like `/profile` after he has logged in but before finishing initial setup, user will be redirected to the `/profile` page and see the page for like a second while the backend api is checking its status and finay redirecting to `/quick-setup` page.

Is there any way to stop angular from routing automatically at app start? so I can do it manually?

I don't need nor want to check this on every route change, Just at the app start!

can I somehow use [`Resolve`](https://angular.io/guide/router#resolve-pre-fetching-component-data) for this?

I already have `AuthGuard` to check the auth status but this will be checked on every route change and that's not what i want

Comment: i think you are looking for guards: https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate

Comment: @enno.void nope, as far as I know they are not async! are they?? and beside they are called in every route change, that's not what I want

Comment: i think they can be async as they can return a `Promise` or an `Observable`, but yes they called on every route change to this route.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is what I did to make this work.

First in `app.component`

```
  ngOnInit(): void {    
    //always go to login page to authenticate and then redirect to the requested url
    this.authService.navigateToLogin();
  }
```

```
  navigateToLogin() {
    if (!Util.checkUrl('/logout') && !Util.checkUrl('/signup'))
      this.router.navigate(['/login'], { skipLocationChange: true });
  }
```

In `login.component`, store the `location.pathname` in a cookie so I can redirect to it after login

```
  ngOnInit() {
    if (!Util.checkUrl('/login') && !Util.checkUrl('/', true) && !Util.checkUrl('/#')) {
      this.cookieService.set(COOKIE_LOGIN_REDIRECT, location.pathname, 3600, '/');
    }

    this.authService.verify();
  }
```

`this.authService.verify();` checks with backend to see if user is ok and then redirects to the location stored in the cookie.

```
    let redirect = this.cookieService.get(COOKIE_LOGIN_REDIRECT);
    if (redirect) {
      this.cookieService.delete(COOKIE_LOGIN_REDIRECT, '/');
      redirect = redirect.replace(environment.baseHref, '');
      return this.router.navigateByUrl(redirect);
    }
```